# cron not working as intended

Tags: cron

This works

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/vlc --play-and-exit /home/tc/Music/test.ogg
```

But this doesn't

```
30 8 * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/vlc --play-and-exit /home/tc/Music/test.ogg
```

I want my test.ogg to play every day at 8:30 am. So wrote the above, but for some strange reason it just doesn't play.

But when I make it every minutue, it plays. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Very strange. Could you try and copy the line with `* * * * *` and make a hybrid? Like `30 * * * *`. The only logical explanation I can think of is an invalid character copied, so that's why you should copy a working line and go from there. And this is in the same `crontab` file?

Comment: Yes when I give 30 * * * *, it works. But when I specify the hour 30 9 * * *, it doesn't. And yes I am logged in.

Comment: I answered it, the thing is the BIOS clock is not synced. I rebooted the system and went to BIOS and checked what time it's showing there and for some strange reason it's showing 17:38 and the local time here is (9:35). But when I bootup the system completely the system does show my local time (9:35). So I think cron works on the BIOS time and if BIOS is off your cron is off. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Linux sets UTC as the system time and shows local time based on your timezone. I think the problem may be the 35 vs 38 (minutes) rather than the 9 vs 17 (hours or the timezone).  If this is the case, you need to sync the computer's time with the Internet. What is the output of the command `timedatectl status`? If the output includes "System clock synchronized: no" then you need the set up network sync for time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the BIOS time is not synced to your system time.

Boot your system and press F2 (or Del key, based on what machine you are using), go to BIOS and check the time it's showing there. If it's not matching with your time, then change it to match to your system time (usually by pressing the F5 or F6 keys).

Once it's matched, save the settings and reboot the machine.

Now your cron should work as usual.

So basically, the cron is working on your BIOS time and not what you see on your task bar.

I hope this helps someone else who are losing hopes on cron.